# accordion menu on mobile screen not working

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, mobile, mobile-menu

I am working on a magento ecommerce website https://harissonsbags.com

Here the accordion menu not working on mobile device. But it is working properly on localhost.

Can you please give me any suggestion?

I am using magento 1.9

Comment: Probably off-topic. Feel free to update once you've resolved 404s and perhaps edit with form factor, browser, and of course screen shots